# OnItemSaved event not triggering in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I have added `OnItemSaved` event in a config file. I also added same method in a `.cs` file. But when I edit any field and save in Content Editor, the event is not triggering.

This is my event handler

```
    public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentItem = Event.ExtractParameter<Item>(e, 0);

        if (currentItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (currentItem.TemplateID == Consts.TemplateIds.EventPageId)
        {
            var eventId = currentItem.Fields[Consts.TemplateIds.EventIdentificationTemplateId]?.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventId))
            {
                var storiesApiResult = this.multiSaleStoriesApiService.GetStoriesByAuctionId(new Guid(eventId));
                Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiSaleStoriesField = currentItem.Fields["_MultiSaleStories"];
                var stories = storiesApiResult.Value.Stories;
                foreach (var story in stories)
                {
                    multiSaleStoriesField.Add(story.Id.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and following is the config file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="Discovery.Feature.MultiSaleLandingPages.Events.EventPageCreationEvent, Discovery.Feature.MultiSaleLandingPages" resolve="true" method="OnItemSaved">
          <database>master</database>
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please include the config patch where you register the `OnItemSaved` event handler and the C# code of your event handler. Without these details it is impossible to replicate this issue and answer your question. Also, do you see any error messages in Sitecore log file after saving an item in Content Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Your config file and `OnItemSaved` method signature look correct. The only missing bit is placing item in [editing mode](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/place-an-item-in-editing-mode.html) if you want to save field changes programmatically.

Please try wrapping your code in `using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(currentItem))` or adding `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()` statements to save changes to the database, for example:

```
    if (currentItem.TemplateID == Consts.TemplateIds.EventPageId)
    {
        var eventId = currentItem.Fields[Consts.TemplateIds.EventIdentificationTemplateId]?.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventId))
        {
            var storiesApiResult = this.multiSaleStoriesApiService.GetStoriesByAuctionId(new Guid(eventId));
            Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiSaleStoriesField = currentItem.Fields["_MultiSaleStories"];
            var stories = storiesApiResult.Value.Stories;
            currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            foreach (var story in stories)
            {
                multiSaleStoriesField.Add(story.Id.ToString());
            }
            currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap database in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="Discovery.Feature.MultiSaleLandingPages.Events.EventPageCreationEvent, Discovery.Feature.MultiSaleLandingPages" resolve="true" method="OnItemSaved">
<includedDatabases hint="list:AddDatabase">         
  <database>master</database>
</includedDatabases>
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Also, verify 'role:define' is correct in web.config

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).